# finding last character on if condition excel

Tags: excel

Can you tell me if I want to find the last character in Excel based on condition
let say last character if it is A then replace it with X, or if it is b then replace it with Z.
I want to do it with formula

Comment: Do you want this to be case sensitive......or should both a and A be replaced by X?

Comment: it has solved my problem but for the future if it has to be casesenstive then? can you please mention it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your value is in `A1` cell, then try applying the following formula in `B1` cell.

**Formula**

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="a", LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1) &"x", IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="b",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1) & "z",A1))
```

---

If you are looking for last character to be exactly `A`, then try the following formula.

**Formula**

```
=IF(EXACT(RIGHT(A1,1),"A"), LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1) &"X", IF(EXACT(RIGHT(A1,1),"B"),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1) & "Z",A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula.  See the example sheet to understand the values.

**In Example:**

**"A2": Original Text**

**"B2": Result**

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="A",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"X"),IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="B",REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"Z"),A2))
```

[image: EXAMPLE]